# Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) returning null

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

I tried all ways but still I am not able to solve this, `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)` is always returning null.

This is my code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();
```

and this is `onConnected()`:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get user's information
        if (login_status == 1) {
            mSignInClicked = false;
            login_status = 0;
            /* This Line is the key */
            Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(LoginFragment.this);

            getProfileInformation();
        } else {
            signOutFromGplus();
        }

    }
```

and this is getProfileInformation()::::
/**
     * Fetching user's information name, email, profile pic
     */'

```
private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        String emailAddr = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Person information is GOT:" + emailAddr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Person signedInUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Person information obj:" + signedInUser, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e("", "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Person information is GOT:" + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X

        } else {

            signOutFromGplus();
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        dialog_google.dismiss();
        ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Android Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="learn.english.from.hinkhoj" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginFragment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_fragment" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you getting any error, post the Logcat. post your code so that we can help

Comment: i am not getting any error logs just this plus.peopleapi.getcurrentperson returns null

Comment: have you enabled api from developer console

Comment: have you added relevant permission in manifest? post your manifest

Comment: is your app in development mode or release mode?

Comment: my app is in debug mode

Comment: I added my manifest file code also

Comment: make sure the SHA you used is same as shown here eclipse>window>preferences>android>build

Comment: are you testing in emulator or device

Comment: my SHA is same, I am using android studio and testing on device

Comment: do you have your apis enabled?

Comment: Yes i enabled the api in console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85284/discussion-between-karan-mer-and-g4gaj).

Answer (score 3):

1) Try adding the following simple code to your callback:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Person me = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (me != null) {
        Person.Name name = me.getName();
        String given = name.getGivenName();
        String family = name.getFamilyName();

        Log.d(TAG, "Given: " + given + ", Family: " + family);
    }
}
```

2) Add **two** SHA1 signatures to the [Google Developers Console / Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com) - one extracted from your real keystore and another for `~/.android/debug.keystore` (that is on Mac and Linux; on Windows search for similar path):

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
```

3) Enable "Google+ API" and "Google Play Android Developer API" in [Google Developers Console / APIs](https://console.developers.google.com):

[image: console]

4) Before debugging run the commands:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE
adb logcat
```

5) If nothing helps - wait few hours. Yesterday evening I struggled with an app issue (`Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson()` returned null no matter what I tried). Today morning the Google minions have fixed it.

Comment: What do you mean with "from YOUR real keystore"?? I getting a SHA1 key when i execute the keytool command but I don't understand what is MY keystore.

Answer (score 0):

Is SHA1 the same between your app and the google console ?
check this thread [Android Google Plus getCurrentPerson returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554310/android-google-plus-getcurrentperson-returns-null)